# How to install mitmproxy certificate on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, mitmproxy

The [document](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/) said " Now start a browser on the device, and visit the magic domain mitm.it."

But I visit the domain mitm.it, it does not give certification but said "If you can see this, traffic is not passing through mitmproxy."

[image]

The link in picture leads to  [document](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/) page I said above.

Update: I install mitmproxy with windows installer.

[image]

Comment: Have you configured your web browser to use mitmproxy as proxy? For installing the MitmProxy root Ca certificate on Windows please read the manual: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to manually set proxy in windows setting for certificate link appear.

[image]

Start `mitm ui` app in start menu.

Open http://127.0.0.1:8081/#/flows

See option to know the port

[image]

Comment: You answer only works for web browsers that use the Windows proxy settings (and have no own proxy settings like Firefox). In my opinion using a web browser like Firefox that has an own proxy config is the preferred option as you otherwise capture a lot of traffic you are not interested in.